# MYSQL Most Frequent Value Given a Certain Category

Tags: mysql, database

How do I find the most frequent flight type, given the Destination?

```
Table: Flight:
+-------------+---------------+
| Destination | Type          |
+-------------+---------------+
| Beijing     | First Class   |
| Beijing     | First Class   |
| Beijing     | First Class   |
| Beijing     | First Class   |
| Beijing     | Coach         |
| London      | Coach         |
| London      | First Class   |
| London      | Coach         |
+-------------+---------------+
```

Every query I've tried so far has given the total number of each flight type as opposed to the most frequent flight type for each destination.

Here is the desired output:

```
+-------------+--------------+-------+
| Destination | Type         | count |
+-------------+--------------+-------+
| Beijing     | First Class  |     4 |
| London      | Coach        |     2 |
+-------------+--------------+-------+
```

---

EDIT:
So I found the easiest way was this:

```
SELECT destination, type, count FROM Flight WHERE total=
(
SELECT MAX(total) FROM Flight fl WHERE fl.destination = Flight.destination
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`. You have to select the rows which have the `MAX` total rows for each group (`Destination, Type`).

```
SELECT Destination, `Type`, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM your_table AS aa
GROUP BY Destination, `Type`
HAVING COUNT(*) = (
    SELECT MAX(each_total) 
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS each_total
        FROM your_table
        GROUP BY Destination, `Type`
    )
)
ORDER BY Destination ASC;
```

Comment: This just gives one tuple, that being the one with the highest count. So result here is (Beijing, First Class, 4). Any idea how to get both tuples?

Comment: Can you make an SQL Fiddle with some sample data so I will be able to check it please?